# Не удается открыть базу данных "TestDB", запрашиваемую именем входа. Не удалось выполнить вход

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Не удается открыть базу данных "TestDB", запрашиваемую именем входа. Не удалось выполнить вход. При входе в систему пользователя "MicrosoftAccount\" произошла ошибка.
Попробовал ввести в поля User Id и password логин и пароль от Microsoft аккаунта  и всё равно не получилось, можете подсказать как пофиксить данную проблему, также пробовал вводить локальную Бд тоже ошибку выбило 
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=\SQLEXPRESS; Database=TestDB; Trusted_Connection=true; User Id = ; Password = ;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

Comment: уже пофиксил помощь не нужна.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать вот такой ConnectionString:

```
    Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=TestDB;Trusted_Connection=True;
```